# PHP Vaildate that Code exists and the rest of the record is blank

Tags: php, mysqli

Not going to lie here i might be in over my head with this but any help would be appreciated.

So i have a form that takes a promocode and validates that it exists in the DB but at the same time it is looking to see if the email field is null. i have the code below but i am not sure why it isn't thrpwing the error since i have a record in the DB with that promocode and an email address in its field.

I have a feeling that i am missing something small here or i could be WAY off i am not really sure. I have tried email is null as well as email = ''

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM formdata WHERE (promoCode = '$varPromo' AND email = null)";

$duperaw = $mysqli->query($dupesql);


if($duperaw->num_rows > 0) {
$dupe .= "$varPromo has already been used on $varDate \n";
}
```

Comment: You said that the line with the promocode DOES have an email address in the field? Your query only returns if there is NOT an email address in the field.

Comment: Wow i am an idiot been staring at code too long i was looking for IS NOT NULL. Thanks for stating the obvious here it helped me to get where i needed

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Yepp your exactly right!

Answer (score 1):

Comparison with `NULL`, is `NULL`, which avaluates to false, you can use `IS NULL` or `<=>` if you don't know in advance if either operand is going to be `NULL`, but you need it to be `true` if *both* are `NULL`:

```
mysql> SELECT NULL = NULL;
+-------------+
| NULL = NULL |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT NULL IS  NULL;
+---------------+
| NULL IS  NULL |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT NULL <=> NULL;
+---------------+
| NULL <=> NULL |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```